# How can I modify or handle URL special characters in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web application. The URL for a particular area is coming in as:

http://localhost/General/Bpa%3fapplication%3dTrf%23/GeneralInputs

This causes a "The resource cannot be found." error.  However, if I change the URL to

http://localhost/General/Bpa?application=Trf#/GeneralInputs

then everything works. I can see from using some route debugging tricks that the controller in the first case is: "Bpa?application=Trf#", whereas the second one is: "Bpa", which is correct. How can I account for this or substitute for the encoded characters?

Comment: That URL isn't getting encoded correctly.

Comment: The origin of the URL is where the fix should be placed, not in your application. It looks like double encoding to me.

Comment: This is because your URL contains unsafe characters. You can read more here: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/decoding-percent-with-numbers-encoding-in-urls/

Comment: @CapnJack: No.  None of those characters are unsafe in URLs.

Comment: @recursive ?? That's why no /'s were converted..

Comment: @recursive please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @CapnJack: Ok, I read it.  It's not related.

Comment: You're right.  `/` wasn't escaped, but `?`, `=`, and `#` were.

Comment: @recursive a lot of the tie URLs are passed in without key characters like `?` or `=`. These characters, (if interpreted without SQLInjection defence) can be used write queries to databases that weren't meant to be available to the client. In some cases this opens up access to queries like `SELECT *` or `DELETE`. So it can be pretty problematic.

Comment: Only if you pass parts of the url directly to the database as a query.  You should never do that and it's not related to this question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use this on your url:

```
string fixedUrl = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(yourUrlHere);
```

Hope that works out for you!

Comment: Thanks, Capn Jack. The next Capn Morgan is on me.

Comment: ahaa no problem : )

Answer (score 3):

The encoding of the first URL is wrong. If you look at [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-14) you will find in 2.4 the paragraph

> When a URI is dereferenced, the components and subcomponents
> significant to the scheme-specific dereferencing process (if any)
> must be parsed and separated before the percent-encoded octets within
> those components can be safely decoded, as otherwise the data may be
> mistaken for component delimiters.

That means the URL is decomposed by unencoded characters (in this case the ? matters). If the encoded string #3f is used, then the framework would have to look for a controller named "`Bpa?application=Trf#`" and not "`Bpa`". Thus a 404 / resource not found is returned.

You should not fix it on the server side; you will have to change the place where the wrong url `http://localhost/General/Bpa%3fapplication%3dTrf%23/GeneralInputs` is generated.